# How to run a .BAT file when a user logs in to their windows account?

Tags: batch-file

I want to run this .BAT file when a user logs into their windows account:

[image]

[file.bat]

```
start http://www.google.ca
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the batch file to the Windows Startup folder.

Comment: I tried it that didn't work

Comment: What if the user is not logged off but is locked using the WINDOWS + L KEY

Comment: @user2309648 If they are already logged in, your question is "wrong" for the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @crashmstr Yes, I realized that. Sorry, should I make another question?

Answer (score 1):

Add it to the startup folder located here:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\(user)\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

EDIT:
I saw your comment now.
You could add it to your startup directly through the registry:
Run regedit through the RUN (Start+R), then go to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

And add the appropriate path for the .bat

Comment: What if the user is not logged off but is locked using the WINDOWS + L KEY...

Comment: I've never tried this.. Try:
http://www.techimo.com/forum/applications-operating-systems/7344-xp-configure-programs-run-user-logon.html

Comment: @ FunKy : Thanks! So am i changing the default value?

Comment: I changed the default value to the file path but it didn't work